# ubuntu 14.10: ibus only working in the search applicatoin

Tags: ibus

Just installed Ubunut 14.10 (clean install with old $HOME directory). Things are working fine except for one thing: the Chinese input in ibus. It actually works fine in all the search applications triggered by Windows key or ALT key. But nowhere else. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After I tried the following things, it worked for me (I'm not sure the exactly reason that made it work):

1. Run a system update: sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade.
2. Remove ibus-pinyin and install ibus-libpinyin: sudo apt-get remove ibus-pinyin; sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin.
3. Open a terminal and run im-config, then click "OK" and "YES", then select "ibus" and click "OK" twice.
4. Reinstall ibus and ibus-gtk: sudo apt-get --reinstall install ibus; sudo apt-get --reinstall install ibus-gtk
5. Reboot the system